# Weak MAC Algorithm(s) Supported (SSH)

Tags: ssh, authentication, macintosh, algorithms

I have this lines in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
MACs -umac-64@openssh.com,-umac-128@openssh.com,-hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,-umac-64-etm@openssh.com,-umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

But still can do ssh with `ssh -o MACs=hmac-md5-96 user@host`
Also here is the output of `ssh -Q mac`:

```
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

How can I limit it to 256 and 512?

Comment: (1) where are you running which commands? (2) if your config has two lines for (any setting including) `MACs` only the first is used, unless the second is in a selected `Match` block then only the second is used (3) the `-` (also `+` or `^`) syntax applies to the whole list not an individual item (4) `ssh -Q` tells you what is compiled in the code not what is enabled in the config (5) if you use an AEAD cipher, which modern OpenSSH often does unless you change that also, the authentication is never more than 128 bits -- which it doesn't need to be in any case

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for repply
(1) sshd_config file of the host, `ssh -o MACs=hmac-md5-96 user@host` on the client to connect the host, `ssh -Q mac` on the host again. (2) According to this desctiption, I have to concatenate the second at the end of the first line to make it effective? or what do you suggest for it? (3) I just need to disable weak MAC algorithms and I don't know how as none of th emodifications where effective (4) As I mensioned when I try the ssh, it works with any like hmac-md5-96 and the support of my host asked to solve it. What do you suggest?

Comment: As bk has now answered, just add the good ones, you don't need to subtract those that haven't been added. Make sure you have restarted the server after making a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to configure the algorithms you want is to use just something like the first line in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
```

Note that I have sorted the EtM MACs, which are more secure, first and also preferred the more secure options first as well.  As a practical matter, it makes little difference, since the SSH protocol requires that both sides pick the first supported client MAC that the server also supports.  You will need to restart the server to have this value take effect; otherwise, you'll see no change.

The second line in your case simply removes some of the algorithms.  What you didn't remove is HMAC-MD5, which is no longer a good choice.  By specifying only the secure options, the insecure options are automatically removed, so that's the best way to solve this problem.

Note that `ssh -Q mac` lists all the options compiled into the binary and doesn't indicate what's configured.  While many of the options listed are poor choices, unfortunately some people have obsolete and insecure operating systems or hardware that must be supported and having these options can be useful for such a contingency.  Thus, OpenSSH contains multiple options, some of which are disabled by default.

Additionally, if you're using an AEAD cipher like `chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com`, `aes128-gcm@openssh.com`, or `aes256-gcm@openssh.com`, then the MAC values are not used, since an AEAD cipher provides integrity in place of a MAC.  Thus, if you want to test, you may also need to choose a cipher such as `aes256-ctr` that isn't an AEAD, so your test command should look like this:

```
ssh -oMACs=hmac-md5 -oCiphers=aes256-ctr user@host
```

Comment: In addition to or instead of testing bad combinations separately, if you use `ssh -vv` it shows the peer proposal containing all the algorithm lists

Comment: bk2204 thank you for the clear description. I guess it is correct. I have to wait for the weekly security check and make sure about it. 
@dave_thompson_085 thanks for info, do you mean: peer server KEXINIT proposal ?
It is something like debug : MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256 
and many more lines

Comment: @Shrm: that block, yes. Technically 'MACs stoc' and 'MACs ctos' are separate in the protocol and _could_ be different, but OpenSSH doesn't ever make them different.